# CSS ::after pseudo-element alignment

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to extend the background colour in a table head beyond the bounds of the table. I've got it to work on the left side using `th:first-child::before`. I expect `th:last-child::after` to have mirrored behaviour, but it doesn't appear to do that.

I currently use `float` to take the `::before`/`::after` out of the normal flow because `th::before,th::after { position:absolute; top:0; }` seems to consider `body` to be its parent instead of `tr` or `thead`.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/xrUcb/)

Comment: It considers the `body` as parent because no other elements have a `position` set. Also, your example Fiddle has no elements with `position` at all.

Comment: @putvande, yes…I tried the [position method](http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/xrUcb/7/) but it still considered `body` to be its parent.

Comment: @putvande, so it turns out `tr { position:relative }` is not allowed. The closest parent element that can be positioned is `<table>` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jshado1/xrUcb/9/)), but that is above the padding on `th`, which I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `::before` instead of `::after` on the last `th`? It's being floated anyway so it shouldn't matter which end you use.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xrUcb/8/